# AttributeError: 'CuDNNLSTM' object has no attribute 'unroll'

Tags: python, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to use Sherpa framework for population based training with this model

```
    x1 = Input((window_size, 3), name='x1')
    x2 = Input((window_size, 3), name='x2')
    convA1 = Conv1D(hidden_num,11,padding='same',activation='relu')(x1)
    convA2 = Conv1D(10,11,padding='same',activation='relu')(convA1)
    poolA = MaxPooling1D(3)(convA2)
    convB1 = Conv1D(hidden_num,11,padding='same',activation='relu')(x2)
    convB2 = Conv1D(10,11,padding='same',activation='relu')(convB1)
    poolB = MaxPooling1D(3)(convB2)
    AB = concatenate([poolA, poolB])
    lstm1 = Bidirectional(CuDNNLSTM(10, return_sequences=True))(AB)
    drop1 = Dropout(0.25)(lstm1)
    lstm2 = Bidirectional(CuDNNLSTM(10))(drop1)
    drop2 = Dropout(0.25)(lstm2)    
    y1_pred = Dense(4)(drop2)
    y1_pred = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(axis=-1)(y1_pred)
    model = Model(inputs =[x1, x2], outputs = [y1_pred])

    optimizer = Adam(lr=0.0001)
    model.compile(loss='mse',
                optimizer=optimizer,
                metrics=[quaternion_mean_multiplicative_error])
```

But after the run the second generation (for load the saved model) I got this error

> SHERPA Dashboard running. Access via http://127.0.1.1:8884 if on a
> cluster or http://localhost:8884 if running locally. Generation 1
> Creating new model with hidden_num  92
>
> Serving Flask app 'sherpa.app.app'    Debug mode: on 2/2

> [==============================] - 5s 1s/step

> Saving model at: /tmp/tmpihern3zn/1 Traceback (most recent call last):

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/home/arman/Neural Network in Python/RNN/6-DOF-Inertial-Odometry/HPO.py", line 236, in 
> model.save(model_dir) line 282, in _use_input_spec_as_call_signature

> ```
> if self.unroll: AttributeError: 'CuDNNLSTM' object has no attribute 'unroll'
> ```

why `model.save(model_dir)` is caused `AttributeError: 'CuDNNLSTM' object has no attribute 'unroll'`

What this mean?

Comment: Do you have a particular reason for wanting to use `CuDNNLSTM ` instead of the regular `tf.keras.layers.LSTM`?

Comment: An important missing detail is the imports, where did you get CuDNNLSTM from?

Comment: @ClaudiaR I got this error while using LSTM 'Could not load library libcudnn_adv_train.so.8. Error: /home/arman/anaconda3/envs/tf/bin/../lib/libcudnn_ops_train.so.8: undefined symbol: _Z22cudnnGenericOpTensorNdILi3EE13cudnnStatus_tP12cudnnContext16cudnnGenericOp_t21cudnnNanPropagation_tPKdPKvPK17cudnnTensorStructS8_S8_SB_S8_S8_SB_Pv, version libcudnn_ops_infer.so.8
Aborted (core dumped)'

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy what do you mea? Where I download CuDNN? I download it from Nvidia website.

Comment: No, I said CuDNNLSTM, not CuDNN.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I imported from tf,keras.layers

Comment: There could be Tensorflow version mismatch issue as [cuDNNLSTM](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/keras/layers/CuDNNLSTM) is TF 1.x API and you are trying to save or load the TF 1.x model to TF 2.x. You can use `tf.saved_model.save()` api or can use `tf.keras.models.save_model` if saving in keras. Please check this [migration guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate/saved_model) for more detail.